# PHP append same string to multiple other strings in one line?

Tags: php, string-concatenation

Appending to a single string is easy:

```
$string = "saucy";
$output = " you smell ". $string;
print $output;
// you smell saucy.
```

PHP also has a easy way of setting multiple values at once:

```
$aa = $bb = $cc = [];
```

But what if I want to *append* a string to multiple strings simultaneously?

For example:

```
$aa['horses'] = "trolls!";
$stringSomething = "This is better: ";
$stringElse = "This is less worse : ";

foreach($aa as $bb){
   $stringSomething .= $stringElse .= $bb; // THIS line
}

print $stringSomething;
print $stringElse;
```

This outputs:

> This is better: This is less worse : trolls!
> This is less worse : trolls!

What I am curious about is if you can have an output like this:

> This is better: trolls!
> This is less worse : trolls!

Currently all I can see is:

```
foreach($aa as $bb){
   $stringSomething .= $bb;
   $stringElse .= $bb; 
   $stringEntirely .= $bb;
   // .... 

}
```

Is there a way of wrapping this all up into a single line of appending the same value to multiple strings at once?

## NOTE

The question here is NOT "How can I do this on an array", it is asking if there was a shorthand way of doing this with variables, as is possible with initial variable setting ( ie `$a = $b = $c = 67;`).

Comment: No, there is not. But if you stopped using the _terrible_ practice of "numbering" variable names, and used an array instead - then you could loop over the elements in that, and append the value to each.

Comment: @CBroe this was purely for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Still, your data must have _some_ sort of logical relation between those values, I suppose, so that processing them in such a combined way would make sense to begin with ... so it could still be grouped in an array, instead of having "independent" variables lingering around. A `$strings` array with elements under keys `Something`, `Else` and `Entirely` then in this particular instance :-)

Comment: @CBroe Yes I can see what you're saying but I was curious if there was a shortcut in PHP natively for doing this, and it seems there may not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no syntax of any specific shorthand to do this on pure variables.

There are various ways this can be done with *array* values and looping but this would involve adding code lines to the script and mitigate the intention to DRY down the original code.

Answer (score 1):

The way to go would be to have these strings in an array and process like this:

```php
<?php

$aa = [];
$aa['horses'] = "trolls!";
$strings = ["This is better: ", "This is less worse : "];

foreach($aa as $bb){
    foreach ($strings as &$string) {
        $string .= $bb;
    }
}
```

Comment: But you'd need to use references (or directly access the original array element via its key), otherwise the change inside the foreach loop will only be applied to a copy of the data, and not change the original array.

Comment: Thx for feedback, you're right on that. Answer is already updatet with passing by reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it by using dynamic variable and an array with the name of your variables: [dynamic variables](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/language.variables.variable.php)

```
<?php

$aa = [];
$aa['horses'] = "trolls!";
$name1 = "smth";
$name2 = "smthelse";
$strings = ["name1", "name2"];

foreach($aa as $bb){
    foreach ($strings as $string) {
        $$string .= $bb;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map()` by passing references to it:

```
<?php

$suffix = "trolls!";
$string1 = "This is better: ";
$string2 = "This is less worse : ";

array_map(fn(&$s) => $s .= $suffix, [&$string1, &$string2]);

echo "$string1\n";
echo "$string2\n";
```